# Having namespace prefix in Jackson response

Tags: java, jackson

I am not a expert on Java but looking for help on issue we are seeing.  With our java Jackson response , we are trying to build a XML based response but response is coming without a namespace prefix like below

Kindly help

```
<EmployeeResponse **xmlns**="http://test.service.net/com/v1">
    <Reference>SequenceTime="2019-03-07 12.15.01.970236"</Reference>
    <Details>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        </Name>
    </Details>
</EmployeeResponse>
```

However we would like to have the response defined as a space prefix like below where v1 would denote a namespace type and same should be mapped to all child elemetns.

```
<v1:EmployeeResponse xmlns:v1="http://test.service.net/com/v1">
    <v1:Reference>SequenceTime="2019-03-07 12.15.01.970236"</v1:Reference>
    <v1:Details>
        <v1:Name>
            <v1:FirstName>Alex</v1:FirstName>
        </v1:Name>
    </v1:Details>
</v1:EmployeeResponse>
```

Comment: I would start my search here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema